# Rebuilding Vue.js templates inside Laravel from a bundled App.js

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Ok I had a developer I hired a while back to add some features into my app, at time I had never even looked into Vue or how it works. So when he only updated my app.js and not the repos vue files. Thus a year later when we decide to add new features yet again the old ones go * poof * when compiling the bundle.  I have rebuilt most of it but ran into this part where it is importing a file that has no extension.

```
var _underscore = require('underscore');

var _underscore2 = _interopRequireDefault(_underscore);

var _Conversation = require('./Conversation.vue');

var _Conversation2 = _interopRequireDefault(_Conversation);

var _conversation = require('./../../api/conversation');

var _conversation2 = _interopRequireDefault(_conversation);

var _sweetalert = require('sweetalert');

var _sweetalert2 = _interopRequireDefault(_sweetalert);
```

This part here where it has /api/conversation - now you can see this with underscore and sweet alert..  but very confused about this one.. I dug into the app.js to find the reference for this and it was.

```
    [function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

var _vue = require('vue');

var _vue2 = _interopRequireDefault(_vue);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

exports.default = {
    removeConversation: function removeConversation(website_id, conversation_id) {
        return _vue2.default.http.post('/api/chat/' + website_id + '/' + conversation_id + '/remove');
    }
};

},{"vue":41}]
```

So I rebuilt the file in the location it points to the best of my knowledge and and just leave it with no extension and if i leave in an import for vue it then says it has to be a module for import. so if i leave the vue part off it will build but then it doesn't see to do what is intended. If add .vue on the end it adds a lot of extra code on the build and still doesnt' do what is intended. I am think maybe is file has an extension but I just am not familiar enough with Vue to know it. Hoping someone can shine some like on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok seems that the app.js can read a .js file without having the extension on the end.  so this is the file type that I was missing.